# Using Neo4j with Apache Spark

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark, neo4j

I'm trying to use Neo4j with Apache Spark Streaming but I am finding serializability as an issue.

Basically, I want Apache Spark to parse and bundle my data in real time. After, the data has been bundled it should be stored in the database, Neo4j. However, I am getting this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD.foreach(JavaPairRDD.scala:45)
    at twoGrams.Main$4.call(Main.java:102)
    at twoGrams.Main$4.call(Main.java:1)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$2.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$2.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:164)
    ... 17 more
```

Here is my code:

```
output a stream of type: JavaPairDStream<String, ArrayList<String>>

output.foreachRDD(
                new Function2<JavaPairRDD<String,ArrayList<String>>,Time,Void>(){

                    @Override
                    public Void call(
                            JavaPairRDD<String, ArrayList<String>> arg0,
                            Time arg1) throws Exception {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        arg0.foreach(
                                new VoidFunction<Tuple2<String,ArrayList<String>>>(){

                                    @Override
                                    public void call(
                                            Tuple2<String, ArrayList<String>> arg0)
                                            throws Exception {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        try( Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx()){
                                            if(Neo4jOperations.getHMacFromValue(graphDB, arg0._1)!=null)
                                                System.out.println("Alread in Database:" + arg0._1);
                                            else{
                                                Neo4jOperations.createHMac(graphDB, arg0._1);
                                            }
                                            tx.success();
                                        }
                                    }

                        });
                        return null;
                    }



                });
```

Neo4jOperations Class:

```
public class Neo4jOperations{

public static Node getHMacFromValue(GraphDatabaseService graphDB,String value){
        try(ResourceIterator<Node> HMacs=graphDB.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label("HMac"), "value", value).iterator()){
            return HMacs.next();
        }
    }

    public static void createHMac(GraphDatabaseService graphDB,String value){
        Node HMac=graphDB.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("HMac"));
        HMac.setProperty("value", value);
        HMac.setProperty("time", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }
}
```

I know that I have to Serialize the class Neo4jOperations, but I'm able to figure out how. Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In cases where connections to external systems are involved or when dealing with non-serializable objects, it's possible to create those objects directly on the workers and avoid the need of serialization.

```
Given: val stream: DStream = ???
stream.forEachRDD{rdd =>
   rdd.forEachPartition{iter =>
       val nonSerializableConn = new NonSerializableDriver(ip, port)
       iter.foreach(elem => nonSerializableConn.doStuff(elem)
   }
}
```

This pattern amortizes object creation by doing it only once per partition (which will contain many elements)

In long-lived processes, like Spark Streaming, we can further reduce the overhead by keeping a per-VM cache of resources:

```
stream.forEachRDD{rdd =>
   rdd.forEachPartition{iter =>
       val nonSerializableConn = NonSerializableDriver.getConnection(ip, port)
       iter.foreach(elem => nonSerializableConn.doStuff(elem)
   }
}
```

In the latter case, we need to do connection management and close resources when the VM terminates.

Comment: Interesting pattern. I think the issue with this approach is that there is no Java non-serializable driver for Neo4j that I know of. Neo4j's embedded graph database could perhaps be bundled into a fat JAR and sent to Spark. I think it makes more sense to use TinkerPop for something like that though. Finally, Neo4j server exposes a REST API, so drivers are client libraries wrapping HTTP requests. You'd have to make requests durable and use the batch API. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to serialize the transitive dependencies that are included in the Neo4jOperations class. Spark unfortunately just doesn't work that way.

The problem is that the Neo4j traversal API cannot be serialized or bundled and dispatched to Spark. Even if you were to try and bundle Spark into Neo4j, you'd get dependency conflicts with the Jetty servlet versions.

That's why I created [Neo4j Mazerunner](https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-mazerunner). Until a Neo4j Spark connector is created that extends the Spark RDD package's base classes, there won't be an easy way to source data from Neo4j into Spark's runtime.

See [Couchbase's Spark Connector](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-spark-connector/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/couchbase/spark/rdd) to get an idea of what's involved in doing that.

Mazerunner doesn't yet support streaming capabilities, but I have plans to make that happen in the future

Comment: So, basically your suggestion is that there is no way I can connect Spark Streaming and Neo4j ?